# Datastax dse graph installation

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am experimenting with **Datastax Dse** 5.0.5 graph on **ubuntu** machine.

**I am mostly interested in graph part of Datastax enterprise package**.

I have executed these below commands on different terminals

- ./bin/dse cannandra
- ./bin/dse gremlin-console
- ./datastax-studio/bin/server.sh

I am successfully able to start datastax-studio at localhost but with this error

`All DSE gremlin server hosts are currently down or don't have the 'graph' workload set. Please, make sure that hosts are available and have the 'graph' workload and retry`

**What I want to do is**?

I want to create vertex and edges using a java program and want to visualize it on datastax-studio.

For that I have written java program following dse docs but I am confused at which port I should connect my to database and even I am not sure about is I am really going on a right path.

**Could you please guide me for installation dse graph and studio in a proper way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./bin/dse cassandra` will start just the Cassandra workload.

Since it appears you are using a tarball install

`./bin/dse cassandra -g` will start DSE in Graph mode

You can also do:

`./bin/dse cassandra -s -g` to enable search functionality for fuzzy/text/geospatial searching within Graph or Cassandra

`./bin/dse cassandra -k -g` to enable Spark to run OLAP style traversals and Spark analytics on Cassandra data

`./bin/dse cassandra -s -k -g` to enable all workload types for ease of experimentation.

For more info see: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/admin/startDseStandalone.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: but how to resolve this error `All DSE gremlin server hosts are currently down or don't have the 'graph' workload set. Please, make sure that hosts are available and have the 'graph' workload and retry

`

Answer (score 2):

Go to Below Link (if you have installed DSE without service ) : -

/usr/share/dse/resources/graph/gremlin-console/conf

Or go to path where your remote.yaml file is kept .

then check/configure the settings : -

```
hosts: [127.0.0.1]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0,
              config: { serializeResultToString: true, ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry] }}
connectionPool: {
  maxContentLength: 65536000
}
```

Check your host and port . Then stop and restart dse .